# distance-measure method to measure the distance between two matrixes(probability distribution)

Tags: probability, matrices, measure-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

I should find a suitable distance-measure method to measure the distance between two matrixes. The elements of such matrix is 0 to 1, and the sum of the all element is 1, so I think I could treat it as a probability matrix. The distance of such two matrixes could be simple Euclidean distance or even Kullback–Leibler divergence. But the problem is I should take the position of the elements in the matrix into consideration. Give a simple example of what I want to express.

```
    0.92 0.01 0.01        0.01 0.92 0.01       0.01 0.01 0.01
 A= 0.01 0.01 0.01  B=    0.01 0.01 0.01  C=   0.01 0.01 0.01
    0.01 0.01 0.01        0.01 0.01 0.01       0.01 0.01 0.92
```

so if use Euclidean distance, distance(A,B)= distance(A,C) and if pull the matrix into a 9-length vector and then caculate the KL divergence as the coding distance, distance(A,B)=distance(A,C) too

But the truth is that since 0.92 in matrix B is close to the 0.92 in the matrix A than the 0.92 in matrix C, in my work such distribution should be take into consideration and as a result distance(A,B) should be smaller than distance(A,C). By the way, in my real application, the size of the matrix is 50*50.

I think the distance of decrete bivariate probability distribution could solve such problem. I have looked for the distance metric, such as f-divergences, including KL-divergence, Hellinger distance &.etc, Bhattacharyya distance, Rényi entropy and so on, but I haven't found a suitable one to solve my problem.

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: If you define $B':=\left(\begin{matrix}0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\ 0.92 & 0.01 & 0.01 \\ 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01\end{matrix}\right)$, which of the Matrices $B$ and $B'$ are "closer" to $A$? Or have they both the same distance to $A$?

Comment: yes, the same distance

Answer (score 0):

Just one suggestion (too long for a comment):

1. Consider each Matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ as a coordinate system with origin at the left top corner, so each entry $a_{ij}$ has the unique position $(i,j)$.
2. If $A$ and $B$ are given matrices, calculate $C:=|A-B|$ (here, $|\cdot|$ means that you take absolute values of each of the entries) and look for the two largest numbers.
3. If $c_{ij}$ and $c_{kl}$ are these maximal entries, define the distance of $A$ and $B$ by $d(A,B):=(c_{ij}+c_{kl})\cdot||(i-k,j-l)||$, where $||\cdot||$ is any norm of $\mathbb R^2$ you like.

Example: Let $A$, $B$, $B'$ and $C$ be defined as you and I did, respectively. Then
\begin{align*}
|A-B|&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.91 & 0.91 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
|A-B'|&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.91 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.91 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
|A-C|&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.91 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.91 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
|B-B'|&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0.91 & 0 \\
 0.91 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
|B-C|&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0.91 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.91 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
|B'-C|&=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.91 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.91 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align*}
The maximal values of $|A-B|$ are located at $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$, so $d(A,B)=(0.91+0.91)||(0,-1)||=1.82$.

The maximal values of $|A-B'|$ are located at $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$, so $d(A,B')=(0.91+0.91)||(-1,0)||=1.82$.

The maximal values of $|A-C|$ are located at $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$, so $d(A,C)=(0.91+0.91)||(-2,-2)||=1.82\cdot\sqrt{8}\approx 5.15$.
And so on. Here I used the Euclidian norm for $||\cdot||$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I take your answer into carelful consideration just now, and then if there are three or more maximal entries(totally n), how to caculate the distance?      for example: 
       0.3 0.3  0.01
|A-B|= 0.3 0.01 0.02
       0.3 0.02 0.03

Comment: I mean, first row: 0.3 0.3 0.01 second row: 0.3 0.01 0.02 third row: 0.3 0.02 0.03 .  the comment doesn't have line-feed

Comment: so it could be cacualte like this? : sum((cij+ckl)⋅||(i−k,j−l)||) it seems to work well! Okay, let me think again careful about such metric method. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked this case. But your summation seems to work well. You can also pick those maximal entries which have the maximal distance to each other. But this doesnt have to be unique... I think your idea is better.